# ConstraintsViolationException not getting triggered between 2 methods in the same Service Layer

Tags: java, spring-boot, javax.validation

```
@Service
@Validated
public class ValidateService {

    public void testValidation(String notValidated) {
        testValidationNotNull(notValidated);
    }

    public void testValidationNotNull(@NotNull String validated) {
        validated.isBlank();
    }

}
```

I am expecting to get ConstraintViolationException when testValidation method is executed and notValidated string is null, but instead i get NPE since validated.isBlank() row is getting executed.

Is this the wanted bahavior from javax.validation.constraints.NotNull when the method is being called from another method in the same service layer?

Below are 2 test methods: 1 triggers NPE, 2 triggers ConstraintViolationException

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ValidateServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ValidateService sut;

    // test that triggers NPE instead of ConstraintViolationException
    @Test
    public void testValidation() {
        sut.testValidation(null);
    }

    // green test which triggers ConstraintViolationException 
    @Test
    public void testValidationNotNull_shouldThrowConstraintsViolationException() {
        final ConstraintViolationException violationException = assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () ->  sut.testValidationNotNull(null));
        assertEquals("testValidationNotNull.validated: must not be null", violationException.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing `null` as a method argument and after it you are trying to invoke `isBlank()` from `String` but if you are going to check the java docs of `String` class, before of all there is writing.

```
` * Unless otherwise noted, passing a {@code null} argument to a constructor
 * or method in this class will cause a {@link NullPointerException} to be
 * thrown.`
```

it is the reason.

By the way I recommend you to check all answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419087/stringutils-isblank-vs-string-isempty) to have more details why. There also is present some good references to documentation.

The reason is simple:

**Annotation has no effect because there’s no validator to enforce it.** in another way :

**@NotNull is just an annotation. Annotations do nothing on their own. They need an annotation processor at compile time, or something that processes it at runtime.**

It is the reason why you got `NullPointerException` to fix it you also should invoke `ConstraintViolationException` as in second test-case

Comment: The point is that the isBlank() method shouldn't be triggered at all and ConstraintsViolationException should be thrown since the string method parameter is annotated with @NotNull.

Comment: i just updated my answer, can you check ?

Comment: Can you please carefully read my post since you are missing the point. I do not care how  to fix the NPE. My question is: "Is this the wanted bahavior from javax.validation.constraints.NotNull when the method is being called from another method in the same service layer?"

Comment: i read it carefully and the answer is `yes` it is an wanted behavior, to test it just do what i wrote in the answer )

Comment: what you are basically saying is that if  i do this the first test will be green correct? But it is not since 
Expected :javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException
Actual   :java.lang.NullPointerException
    @Test
    public void testValidation() {
        final ConstraintViolationException violationException = assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () ->  sut.testValidation(null));
        assertEquals("testValidation.testValidationNotNull.validated: must not be null", violationException.getMessage());
    }

Comment: from question and comments i understood that expected behavior is `ConstraintViolationException.class` not NPE, am i right ?

Comment: From a `ValidateServiceTest` instance itself from one method `testValidation(String)` to another method `this.testValidationNotNull(String)` is called, it does not process any annotation. This is a direct call from one method to the other. There is NO interceptor to process annotations. From one BEAN to another Autowired Bean if you call a method, then some framework comes into the picture and it intercepts that call and processes annotations like @Transactional, @NotNull, etc. But when within a class, from one method to another method, nothing will happen.

Comment: the method naming may be a little confusing that is why i asked you to read it the question again. We have 2 methods. Method1 doesn't enforce validation and allows a null string but also passes that null string to Method2 which doesn't allow null values by the @NotNull annotation. In this case the not null annotation validation is not getting triggered and that is a messed up behavior if it is so wanted. When we separately call lets say from the controller Method2 with a string null arg here the validation is triggered

Comment: Your 2nd test calls `sut.testValidationNotNull(null)` where `sut` is an autowired bean. So, `@NotNull` is effective.  But not from inside `ValidateService` itself when you call `this.testValidationNotNull` from `testValidation`

Comment: @Ishan is there any way to enforce the validation in the same service and not having to write if string == null throw new IllegalArgumentException("not null")

Comment: When you want to enforce validation, call the method that has `@NotNull` from outside the Bean through an autowired (managed) instance.  That's the only possibility.  Remember, whenever from within the bean itself, if you call any other method of the same instance - that will get called directly - without any framework interception coming into picture.

Comment: I don't know the exact usecase, but from the looks of it, I believe you should not have method `testValidation` at all. Just have `public void testValidationNotNull(@NotNull String validated)` which always gets called from the outside (on a managed bean) and always `@NotNull` is processed. Framework validates the parameter BEFORE actually reaching your method `testValidationNotNull` and raises constraint violation exception. INSIDE your method `testValidationNotNull`, you are 100% sure that the parameter is NOT NULL.

Comment: the use-case is a long method calling small methods calling smaller methods in a cron job and the parameter to be validated is also a set that should not be empty where the set comes from an object where the set itself can also be null

Comment: and would be a lot of monkey work to go in every each method and make the validation myself

Comment: Then have Autowired small bean instance in the larger bean.  In the small bean you can have another Autowired SMALLER bean.  Then framework will come into the picture.  Have chains of autowired instances.  But never call `this.somemethod()` - this will not have any annotations processed.  But have `anotherBean.somemethod()` where `@Autowired anotherBean` exists in this instance.

Comment: i guess that is the more reasonable fix

Comment: Added that fix also in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From a `ValidateServiceTest` instance itself from one method `testValidation(String)` another method `this.testValidationNotNull(String)` is called, it does not process any annotation. This is a direct call from one method to the other. There is NO interceptor to process annotations. From one BEAN to another Autowired Bean if you call a method, then some framework comes into the picture and it intercepts that call and processes annotations like `@Transactional`, `@NotNull`, etc. But within a class, from one method to another method, nothing will happen.

Your 2nd test calls `sut.testValidationNotNull(null)` where `sut` is an autowired bean. So, `@NotNull` is effective. But not from inside `ValidateService` instance itself when you call `this.testValidationNotNull` from `testValidation`

When you want to enforce validation, call the method that has `@NotNull` from outside the Bean through an autowired (managed) instance. That's the only possibility. Remember, whenever from within the bean itself, if you call any other method on the same instance - that will get called directly - without any framework interception coming into the picture.

I don't know the exact usecase, but from the looks of it, I believe you should not have method `testValidation` at all. Just have `public void testValidationNotNull(@NotNull String validated)` which always gets called from the outside (on a managed bean instance) and `@NotNull` will always be processed. Framework validates the parameter BEFORE actually reaching your method `testValidationNotNull` and raises constraint violation exception. INSIDE your method `testValidationNotNull`, you are 100% sure that the parameter is NOT NULL.

You can have `@Autowired smallBean` in the large bean.  Then call `smallBean.someSmallMethod(String)` - which would process annotations before calling `someSmallMethod`.

Then have `@Autowired smallerBean` in the `smallBean` class. Call `smallerBean.someSmallerMethod(String)` - which would process annotations before actually reaching `someSmallerMethod`.