# What is the difference between & and && in if statement in java?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference in & and &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-in-and)

```
if (true && true) {
    System.out.println("test if");
}

if (true & true) {
    System.out.println("test if");
}
```

both are give same output.why ?

Comment: `&&` is logical operator while `&` is bitwise operator.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-in-and). Same question as yours.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199666/difference-between-and-in-java

Comment: Check out this question and answer from last year.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-in-and

Answer (score 6):

`&&` short-circuits, wheras `&` doesn't. Example:

```
if (methodA() && methodB()) {
    ...
}
```

In that case, if `methodA` already returns false, `methodB` is not called. Formally, if you have an expression `a && b`, `b` is only evaluated if `a` evaluated to `true`.

Apart from the obvious performance benefit, this is particularly useful for `null` checks:

```
if (x != null && x.getSomeValue()) {
    ...
}
```

If you used a s single `&` here, `x.getSomeValue()` would be evaluated even if `x` were `null`, resulting in an exception.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you don't test the second part of the if : the `&&` operator executes from left to right and stops at the first `false` value.

This may be useful in this case :

```
if (a!=null && a.doSomething()==23) {
```

because it prevents a nullPointerException.

When you test boolean conditions, always use `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a [bit operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

`&&` logically [links two booleans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)

Answer (score 1):

Please see:
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=16530

> It depends on the type of the arguments...
>
> For integer arguments, the single ampersand ("&")is the "bit-wise AND"
>   operator. The double ampersand ("&&") is not defined for anything but
>   two boolean arguments.
>
> For boolean arguments, the single ampersand constitutes the
>   (unconditional) "logical AND" operator while the double ampersand
>   ("&&") is the "conditional logical AND" operator. That is to say that
>   the single ampersand always evaluates both arguments whereas the
>   double ampersand will only evaluate the second argument if the first
>   argument is true.
>
> For all other argument types and combinations, a compile-time error
>   should occur.

Answer (score 0):

In & statetment it will check both left side and right side statements.in && will check only one side of statement(if one side is true it will not check other side)

Answer (score 0):

&& is the logical AND

so you want to make sure BOTH statements become true.

& is the bitwise AND operator

Have a look here:

http://www.javaforstudents.co.uk/TrueFalse

Answer (score 0):

&& is logical and. 
true && true is true and everything else is false.
& is bitwise and.
(10 & 8) = 8