# need explanation on past paper, & Operator

Tags: java, operators, logical-operators

I'm doing past paper for exam

```
public static void triangleTest( int a, int b, int c) 
{
    if ( a > 0 & b > 0 & c > 0 ) 
    { 
        if ( a==b || b==c ); 
        { 
            System.out.println("Equilateral"); 
        }
        else if ( a==b || a==c || b!=c ) 
            System.out.println("Scalene"); 
        }
        else if ( a+b>c && a+c>b || b+c>a ); 
        {
            System.out.println(Isoceles); 
        } 
    }
    else 
    { 
        System.out.println(""); 
    } 
}
```

I have been given this code and told to find mistakes, and when i checked the answers

```
if ( a > 0 & b > 0 & c > 0 )
```

this has been identified as mistake and `&&` were meant to be used instead of `&` I ran the code and it worked fine with `&`, so my question would be what's what's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: How did you copy line numbers in your code?

Comment: There is the semicolon in `if ( a==b || b==c );`. `"Equilateral"` will always be printed, whatever the values of a,b and c are.

Comment: Also note that `System.out.println(Isoceles);` won't compile (with the code you provided).

Comment: at least you can format question properly before posting :p
however you can refer answer.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is a `bitwise operator` whereas `&&` is a `logical and operator`.

Principles of short circuit does not apply in bitwise and operator i.e `&`.

& <-- verifies both operands

&& <-- stops evaluating if the first operand evaluates to false since the result will be false

Comment: for boolean arguments would I be correct in saying that doesn't matter however? And that the difference is that & is not short circuited?

Comment: `&` also works as a logical and operator.

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes principles of short circuit does not apply in bitwise and operator i.e `&`.

Comment: @Keppil Yes it can be used but the terminology is so. `&` is bitwise and `&&` is logical. You can refer to accepted answer of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199666/difference-between-and-in-java).

Comment: @AniketThakur: So maybe a link to that answer/question in the comments would be more appropriate than to copy it here as a new answer?

Comment: @Keppil I searched it after seeing your comment. If i had know a similar problem is already present that would be my course of action.

Answer (score 0):

**&** evaluates both values

where as **&&** checks the first one if it's false it sets result as false.

Comment: So it would be fair to say that the code as written is less efficient but not really "wrong"

Comment: Well as far as this question is concerned if

**( a > 0 & b > 0 & c > 0 )**

 this works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `&` it will check second condition although first is `false`.
While in `&&` it will not check next condition if first is `false`.

In some case it may cause exceptions.
For ex:

```
// Some Code

if ( a != null & a.length() > 0 ){
//coding part
}
```

above code will throw `NullPointerException` with `&` if `a` is `null`. because it will check second condition every time either first is `true` or `false`.

so it will go like this...

```
// Some Code

if ( a !=null && a.length() > 0 ){
//coding part
}
```

For more : [refer this SO Que](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and)

Answer (score 0):

### Short circuiting leads to efficient code

&& is the `logical and` and it is short circuited. & is the `bitwise and`. Although for other cases it is very different; for booleans the (practical) difference is just that it doesn't short circuit.

Short circuiting means it skips evaluating conditions that can't affect the outcome. For exampple

```
if(cheapTest() && expensiveTest() && expensiveTest2())
```

If the first test is false the expresion must be false, so it can not bother with the expensive tests.

```
if(FALSE && DONTCARE && DONTCARE)
```

The reverse is true for | vs ||.

### Protection against exceptions

This can be even more important where the second test may raise exceptions if evaluated, for example

```
if (someObject!=null && someObject.someTest())
```

In this case if `someObject` is null then `someObject.someTest()` never runs, this is a common pattern when null values are expected. Where you to use the `bitwise and` both tests would run in all cases and if `someObject` was null you would recieve a `NullPointerException`