# Considering two java examples given below , I am unable to get how value of 'i' is different in result?

Tags: java

Case 1:

```
boolean t=true;
boolean f= false,b;

b=(t && ((i++)==0));
b=(f && ((i+=2)>0));

System.out.println(i); // prints i=1
```

Case 2:

```
boolean t=true;
boolean f= false,b;

b=(t & ((i++)==0));
b=(f & ((i+=2)>0));

System.out.println(i); // prints i=3
```

Comment: what is your question?/

Comment: Where `i` is declared?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199666/difference-between-and-in-java

Comment: `&` is the bitwise-AND operator.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

case 1 :
`(f && ((i+=2)>0` --> f is false, so second statement will not be executed.

case 2 :you are not using binary `&&` , you are using bitwise `&`, so, `i=i+2` will be executed. So result is 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you use logical and (&&) and the first operand is false, then the other operand is not evaluated.

```
b=(f && ((i+=2)>0));
```

here the `(i+=2)` never happens.

When you do a bitwise and (&), both operands are evaluated. `(i+=2)` is executed, hence the different result. To learn more about operators in Java, read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 0):

`&  = arithmetic AND`

`&& = logical AND`

in this code

`b=(t & ((i++)==0));

b=(f & ((i+=2)>0));`

`i` is incremented

In the code

`b=(f && ((i+=2)>0));`

a "short circuit" is preformed.

f is false for so the rest of the equation does not need to be calculated so i is not increased by 2.

Comment: thank you all for your answers