# Explicitly evaluate both conditions when using Boolean AND

Tags: java, python

I'm not that familiar with Python. From Java I know that in conditionals, if we want have both the operands of `&&` evaluated, we use `&` instead. For example:

```java
if ( x == 2 & y++ == 3)
    // do this
```

But I'm working in python 2.7 and I want to perform operation like:

```py
if x == 2 and myList.pop() == 3:
    # do this
```

But **both** operands of `and` must execute.

In Python, the first comparison would be performed and if it was false, the 2nd comparison would be skipped. But I want both of them to execute even if first comparison returned False. 
Is there any solution for this in Python?

Comment: In your case just flip the conditions in your `if` block, because `x == 2` doesn't change anything

Comment: In this case, just flip the conditions.

Comment: you need to or between them which will evaluate the pop if x != 2

Comment: FYI: in Java the second operand will not execute either if the first one is false - with logical `&&`. Looking at binary `&` has led you astray.

Comment: I can Flip the conditions but what in case we've pop() called in both operands?

Comment: @maksimov. In Java, `&` and `&&` are both logical operators (when applied to boolean operands). The difference between the two is that `&&` uses short-circuit evaluation, and `&` does not. When applied to for example `int`s, `&` is of course a bitwise operation, but that is not the case here.

Comment: @Hoopje Thanks for clarifying this! In fairness it's been awhile since I've used any bitwise operators in Java, it's nice to get a refresher once in a while. Googled up the spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663428/strange-if-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd just execute the conditions first, before testing with `and`:

```
# explicitly execute the conditions first, compare the outcomes later
test1, test2 = x == 2, myList.pop() == 3
if test1 and test2:
```

For your case that can be simplified down to just the `myList.pop()` call:

```
# explicitly pop a value from myList, regardless of what x == 2 returns
myList_value = myList.pop()
if x == 2 and myList_value == 3:
```

Of course, you could also just have swapped the tests:

```
if myList.pop() == 3 and x == 2:
```

to ensure that the `list.pop()` method is always executed.

Otherwise, the `&` bitwise operator is overloaded for Python booleans just like it is in Java:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for a, b in product([False, True], repeat=2):
...     print('{a!r:5} and {b!r:5}: {o1!r:5}    {a!r:5} & {b!r:5}: {o2!r:5}'.format(a=a, b=b, o1=a and b, o2=a & b))
... 
False and False: False    False & False: False
False and True : False    False & True : False
True  and False: False    True  & False: False
True  and True : True     True  & True : True
```

And as such you can use it to avoid short-circuiting, but *only if both operands are booleans*:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print 'called!'
...     return False
... 
>>> def bar():
...     print 'also called!'
...     return False
... 
>>> foo() and bar()
called!
False
>>> foo() & bar()
called!
also called!
False
```

However, I'd consider making use of this *unpythonic*, and indicative of bad coding style. Restructure your code to not have to rely on this in the first place.

Comment: By the way @eMAD, I don't think the & operator in Java does what you are describing.  Absent some exotic overloading, what it is actually doing is a bitwise AND operation between two expressions.  See this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: @rchang actually [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199666/difference-between-and-in-java) made me think this

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters but Explicitly evaluating this means Python doesn't have a solution for this! Though Python is famous for doing large things in few lines. But in this case NOT!

Comment: @eMAD: but it *does* have a solution; just restructure your test. If your code is failing because of short-circuiting you need to re-think your code instead of blaming the tools.

Comment: @rchang. Java is not C or C++, where booleans are basically ints in disguise. In Java, operators can have different semantics when applied to different types. `&` applied to boolean operands is *not* a bitwise "and", it is a *logical* "and" without short-circuit evaluation. The operator `&` applied to operands of type `int` (for example) is a bitwise operation.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator exists in python. It will call the `__and__` magic method, which is meant to perform a bitwise and operation on the operands

eg.

```
assert 3 & 6 == 2
assert True & 3 == 1

x = 0
y = [3]
assert not(x == 2 & y.pop() == 3)
assert y == []
```

However, you want to test that two things are true, rather than doing a bitwise operation. You would be best off reordinging the clauses of the condition or executing the separate conditions before hand and testing afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's built-in `all()` or `any()` functions to avoid short-circuit evaluation.

In order to achieve `&`, you can easily use `all()`:

```
if (all([cond1, cond2])):
    ...
```

Likewise for `|`, you can use `any()`.

Comment: This doesn't actually work; `all([cond1, cond2])` *would* work (e.g. pass in a list). But it is a lot more verbose and less clear as to what you are doing compared to just storing `cond1` and `cond2` separately first.