# Strange if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I found this strange `if`-statement in somebody else’s code:

```
if variable & 1 == 0:
```

I don't understand it. It should have two `==`, right?

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: What is probably confusing is the &. This is one of Python's bitwise operators. A good post examining that can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage).

Comment: May I ask where you found that? I don't often see bitwise operators in Python.

Comment: It's the same as `variable % 2 == 0` for `int`egers.

Comment: The use of a bitwise operator rather than the much more readable `variable % 2 == 0` (or just `not variable % 2`) is exactly why I'm curious about the story behind this.

Comment: Looks like dark magic. You have evil compiler.

Comment: @Navith I'm trying to debug this: https://github.com/chpatrick/hubsan you can find this statement in the hubsan.py line 79

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: that depends on your background.  Personally, I find the bitwise version more readable.  I wouldn't have to think too hard to convert "is even" to "bit 0 is clear", but I would have to think. :-)

Comment: Is there a typo in your question?  You ask if the statement should have two equals (`==`), but if do see those between the `1` and the `0`.

Comment: you should probably parenthesize `variable & 1` since the bitwise and has a lower precedence than equal to in many languages http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/dmr-on-or.html

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 depends on what is meant. For me `variable % 2 == 0` is "variable is not divisible by 2" (variable is a number) and `variable & 1 == 0` is "bit 0 is unset" (variable is a bit vector). In line 79 the code reads hardware register so thinking about it as number is not useful (operations like `+` or `*` don't make sense) - and so is checking if number is odd or even. OTOH checking if bit 0 or 1 are set do make sense.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The conditional is a [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) comparison:

```
>>> 1 & 1
1
>>> 0 & 1
0
>>> a = 1
>>> a & 1 == 0
False
>>> b = 0
>>> b & 1 == 0
True
```

---

As many of the comments say, for integers this conditional is True for evens and False for odds. The prevalent way to write this is `if variable % 2 == 0:` or `if not variable % 2:`

Using `timeit` we can see that there isn't much difference in performance.

**`n & 1`**`("== 0" and "not")`

```
>>> timeit.Timer("bitwiseIsEven(1)", "def bitwiseIsEven(n): return n & 1 == 0").repeat(4, 10**6)
[0.2037370204925537, 0.20333600044250488, 0.2028651237487793, 0.20192503929138184]

>>> timeit.Timer("bitwiseIsEven(1)", "def bitwiseIsEven(n): return not n & 1").repeat(4, 10**6)
[0.18392395973205566, 0.18273091316223145, 0.1830739974975586, 0.18445897102355957]
```

**`n % 2`**`("== 0" and "not")`

```
>>> timeit.Timer("modIsEven(1)", "def modIsEven(n): return n % 2 == 0").repeat(4, 10**6)
[0.22193098068237305, 0.22170782089233398, 0.21924591064453125, 0.21947598457336426]

>>> timeit.Timer("modIsEven(1)", "def modIsEven(n): return not n % 2").repeat(4, 10**6)
[0.20426011085510254, 0.2046220302581787, 0.2040550708770752, 0.2044820785522461]
```

**Overloaded Operators:**

Both the `%` and `&` operators are overloaded.

The bitwise and operator is overloaded for [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). `s.intersection(t)` is equivalent to `s & t` and returns a "new set with elements common to s and t".

```
>>> {1} & {1}
set([1])
```

This doesn't effect our conditional:

```
>>> def bitwiseIsEven(n):
...   return n & 1 == 0

>>> bitwiseIsEven('1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in bitwiseIsEven
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
>>> bitwiseIsEven({1})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in bitwiseIsEven
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'int'
```

The modulo operator will also throw `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)` for most non-ints.

```
>>> def modIsEven(n):
...   return n % 2 == 0

>>> modIsEven({1})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in modIsEven
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'set' and 'int'
```

It is overloaded as a string interpolation operator for the old [`%-formatting`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). It throws `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` if a string is used for the comparison.

```
>>> modIsEven('1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in modIsEven
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

This won't throw if the string includes a valid conversion specifier.

```
>>> modIsEven('%d')
False
```

Comment: It is also useful to note that (for integers), this trick will tell you if the number is even (`True`) or odd (`False`).

Comment: @baum you should make that an answer - looks like you got it (:  btw: afaik & is only defined for integers (and ducks that look like them ;)

Answer (score 29):

This code just checks if the lowest bit of `variable` is a 0.  Based on operator precedence this is:

```
if (variable & 1) == 0:
```

First AND the lowest bit with one (extract just the lowest bit), then check if it is 0.

Answer (score 14):

The & is a [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). It returns an integer with 1 bit for every bit of its two operands that are both 1, and 0 in all other places. For example:

```
a = 10 # 0b1010
b = 6  # 0b0110
a & b  # 0b0010
```

Now, if you have `variable & 1`, you're comparing `variable` against `0b1` which will only return 1 if that last digit in the binary representation is a 1, otherwise a 0.

Answer (score 6):

Your only concern is probably the operator `&`. It is a **bitwise and** which takes the binary format of the two operands and perform "logic and" on each pair of bits.

For your example, consider the following:

```
variable = 2  #0b0010
if variable & 1 == 0:
    print "condition satisfied" # satisfied, 0b0010 & 0b0001 = 0

variable = 5  #0b0101
if variable & 1 == 0:
    print "condition satisfied" # not satisfied, 0b0101 & 0b0001 = 1
```

**Note:**

```
variable = 6  #0b0110
if variable & 2 == 0:
    print "condition satisfied" # not satisfied, 0b0110 & 0b0010 = 2 (0b0010)
```

Comment: There is a typo in your answer, in the first if comment, you left 0b0101 (5) instead of 0b0010 (2)