# Write a program in java to print the sum of all numbers from 50 to 250(inclusive of 50 and 250) that are multiples of 3 and not divisible by 9

Tags: java, arrays

/* when I run this code there is no error in fact output generated is also correct but I want to know what is the logical error in this code? please can any one explain what is the logical error. */

```
class abc
    {
        public static void main(String arg[]){
        int sum=0;
        //for-loop for numbers 50-250
        for(int i=50;i<251;i++){
            // condition to check if number should be divided by 3 and not divided by 9 
            if(i%3==0 & i%9!=0){
                //individual number which are selected in loop
                System.out.println(i);
                //adding values of array so that total sum can be calculated
                sum=sum+i;   
            }   
        }
        //final display output for the code 
        System.out.println("the sum of intergers from 50 to 250 that are multiples of 3 and not divisible by 9 \n"+sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing another ampersad (&) in the condition. it should be  `i%3==0 && i%9!=0` to use logical AND

Comment: the logic of your code looks fine. Why are you saying that the result isn't right?

Comment: Atlease convert the Home work Query to something else Like you already worked with Lilly

Answer (score 2):

My philosophy is "less code == less bugs":

```
int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(50, 250)
    .filter(i -> i % 3 == 0)
    .filter(i -> i % 9 != 0)
    .sum();
```

One line. Easy to read and understand. No bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if(i%3==0 & i%9!=0){
```

to this:

```
if(i%3==0 && i%9!=0){
```

& = bitwise and operator

&& = logical operator

[Difference between & and && in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199666/difference-between-and-in-java)

Comment: `&` still works as intended, but it isn't subjected to short-circuiting. So your answer doesn't change the result...

Comment: Correct. I am taking a guess as to what the OP is referring to as the "logical error" in the code. OP stated in the question that the output was correct.

Comment: The two versions of code have identical behaviour. There is no difference whatsoever. There may be a barely measurable (nanoseconds) performance difference favouring `&&` over `&`

Answer (score 0):

The only problems I saw were:

- The variable `sum` was undeclared
- Use `&&` in place of `&`

---

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 50; i <= 250; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 9 != 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
        sum = sum + i;
    }
}
System.out.println("the sum of intergers from 50 to 250 that are multiples of 3 and not divisible by 9 \n" + sum);
```

Comment: `sum` was declared, it's hidden in the horrifying formatting

Comment: Ah yeah, I just noticed that.

Comment: uploaded code is working code. god knows what OP is on about. it just has some really horrible stylistic issues.

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of touching every single value from 50 to 250 like you would do here `for(int i=50;i<251;i++)`, you can consider something like this...

```
int i = 48;
int sum = 0;
while(i < 250) {
    i += 3;
    if(i%9 != 0)
        sum += i;
}
```

This is somewhat optimized in the sense that I am skipping over values that I know are not possible candidates.

But, there is a much bigger issue in your code. The following code block prints `true`, sure. But, it is a *bad idea* to depend on the `&` since that is not its job. The `&` is for bitwise AND whereas the `&&` is for logical AND, which is what you are trying to do.

```
boolean t = true;
boolean f = false;
System.out.println(f&t);
```

Why?

In Java, if it is a `&&` operation, as soon as you find the first `false`, you are sure that the expression will evaluate to false. Meanwhile, in your implementation, it would need to evaluate both sides. `f&t` will evaluate to false, but the JVM would need to look at both the `f` and `t` variables. Meanwhile, on using `&&`, it wouldn't even need to look at the `t`.

Comment: I did used both "&&" also "&" but its still saying there some logical error

Comment: @lilly What do you mean by `its still saying there some logical error`? What is the error?