# Refer to a method and check Input

Tags: java, csv, methods

I have created a **method** that checks if an Input is between the size of column in a csv File.

```
 public static boolean isValidNumber(String uInput) {

  Long convert = Long.parselong (uInput); 
  int convert2 = (int) convert;// Need to do this because of the JOptionPane
  if(colmn.length > convert) {
  System.out.println("The Column exists.");
   } 
    else { System.out.println("The Column doesn't exists.");}

 return true; }}
```

And in the **main** method i refer to the **isValidNumber-Method**

```
 // some previous code

 do { String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog);
  } while(isValidNumber(userInput));} 


 //next code
```

So i can't get out of the Loop even if the userInput is correct and exists in the csv-file. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Please elaborate what issue you are facing

Comment: @DarkKnight sorry, done.

Comment: can you please elaborate which line you are getting error from and where colmn is defined

Comment: I don't get an error, it just doesn't Exit out of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isValidNumber` always returns true and that's why you are not able to get out of the loop.

Try using below--

```
public static boolean isValidNumber(String uInput) {

  Long convert = Long.parselong (uInput); 
  int convert2 = (int) convert;// Need to do this because of the JOptionPane
  if(colmn.length > convert) {
  System.out.println("The Column exists.");
   return true;
   } 
    else { System.out.println("The Column doesn't exists."); return false;}

 }
```

Comment: But in the last bracket it tells me that it's missing a return Statement. Why?

Comment: You welcome ! Also, i have  edited code, so probably you will not get any warning or error now.

Comment: Perfect. By the way how can i check if one method is true and continue with the next method. In my Case  do userinput --- while(isValidNumeric && isValidColumn) So if i Input text it can't convert text in the first method. so i wanna execute first one method and then another

Comment: `while(isValidNumber(userInput)&&isValidColumn(userInput1))`, here your first method will get called i.e. `isValidNumber(userInput)`  and if it returns true then only next method gets called.

Comment: but that's a AND condition and it checks both method. how do i check first number and second Column?

Comment: As per [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199666/difference-between-and-in-java) "&& evaluates the left side of the operation, if it's true, it continues and evaluates the right side.", so here your first method i.e. `isValidNumber(userInput)` will always get called and evaluates for true or false. If it is false, it will not call `isValidColumn` method

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your issue is that anything you enter is valid, the problem lies within the `isValidNumber` method itself:

```
public static boolean isValidNumber(String uInput) {

  Long convert = Long.parselong (uInput); 
  int convert2 = (int) convert;// Need to do this because of the JOptionPane
  if(colmn.length > convert) {
    System.out.println("The Column exists.");
  } 
  else { 
    System.out.println("The Column doesn't exists.");
  }

  return true; 
 }
```

This will yield `true` regardless, what you need to do is to move your return statements. After printing, you will need to return `true`/`false` accordingly:

```
public static boolean isValidNumber(String uInput) {

  Long convert = Long.parselong (uInput); 
  int convert2 = (int) convert;// Need to do this because of the JOptionPane
  if(colmn.length > convert) {
    System.out.println("The Column exists.");
    return true;
  } 
  else { 
    System.out.println("The Column doesn't exists.");
    return false;
  }
 }
```

Alternatively:

```
public static boolean isValidNumber(String uInput) {

  Long convert = Long.parselong (uInput); 
  int convert2 = (int) convert;// Need to do this because of the JOptionPane
  if(colmn.length > convert) {
    System.out.println("The Column exists.");
    return true;
  }       

  System.out.println("The Column doesn't exists.");
  return false;      
 }
```

Comment: So i have to return true for the first condition and false for the second? right? Because i've tried this already but at the end of the method i Need to return something too.

Comment: @javach1: I have updated my answer as per your comment.