# Can you connect multiple "not equals to" conditions together in one condition in java?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, inequality

For instance, would this program run:

```
*loop code.......* 
if (variable1 != variable2 != variable3 != variable4){break loop;}
```

Comment: However, then it is comparing variable 2 to variable 4 for instance. I want to make sure none of those variables equal any of the other variables

Answer (score 4):

What you're really trying to test is whether there are any duplicate values in your set of variables. Here's a simple method to test that:

```
static boolean allUnique(Object... values) {
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(values)).size() == values.length;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
if (allUnique(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4)) break loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (new HashSet(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4).size == 4) ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need to use the logical `&&` AND operator.
More info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199666/difference-between-and-in-java) SO answer.

Essentially you will use something like:

```
if (variable1 != variable2 && variable1 != variable3 && variable1 != variable4)
```

This will check that variable 1 is not equal to 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: However, then it is comparing variable 2 to variable 4 for instance. I want to make sure none of those variables equal any of the other variables

Comment: Please give a better example, what are you trying to do in words? Check variable 1 is not equal to 2,3 and 4? Or that none of the variables are the same?

Comment: Sorry my fault, I am trying to make sure that none are the same. Specifically, the program that I'm working on is generating 4 random integers out of 1,000 and I am trying to ensure that none of those ten are the same.

Comment: In that case I would use a hashset as others have already demonstrated.